# Low latency packet processing with shared memory on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, performance, udp, latency

If I was to receive UDP packets on Linux (and I didn't mind changing some of the source code) what would be the fastest way for my application to read the packets?

Would I want to modify the network stack so that once a UDP packet is received it is written to shared memory and have the application access that memory?

Would there be any way for the stack to notify the application to react, rather than have the application continuously poll the shared memory?

Any advice/further resources are welcome- I have only seen:

http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: Sorry, but are you sure, that the normal way of reading UDP packets via recvfrom(2) etc. is not fast enough? Changing the Linux source creates quite a maintenance burden.

Comment: @SegFault unless it directly outputs the packet data to memory using zero copy, then it's not as fast as I would like. I'm not concerned about maintenance- just implementation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is zero-copy UDP packing receiving possibly on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450001/is-zero-copy-udp-packing-receiving-possibly-on-linux)

Comment: You are announcing latency requirements without providing numbers, so right off the bat your question can't be answered.  Step one needs to be to measure your existing latency problems and report them.  Then identify the best solution (hint: the syscall used to read the data is almost never the problem -- look to changing hardware instead).  This question just reeks of premature optimization.

Comment: You will be extremely luck to shave even a μSec from the latency of using a std select / recvfrom loop.  UDP over internet is 10s mSec or ~1 mSec within the server room fabric.  You are looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If latency is a problem and the default UDP network stack does not perform as you wish, then try to use different existing (installable) network stacks.

Example, try [UDP Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_Lite), compare to the standard UDP stack, this particular stack does not perform any checksum on the UDP datagram, thus reducing latencies at the cost of providing corrupted datagram to the application layer.

Side note: you do not need to have a "polling" mechanism. Read the manual of `select` (and it's possible derivative like `pselect` or `ppoll`), with such API, the kernel will "wake up" your application as soon as it has something to read or write in the pipeline.